# To find the maximal and minimal ideals of $Z_9$ , $Z_{10}$, $Z_{14}$, $Z_8$

Tags: ring-theory, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I want to  find the maximal and minimal ideals of $Z_9$ , $Z_{10}$, $Z_{14}$, $Z_8$.

As ideals are subrings of ring, here  ideals will be subrings generated  by elements of $Z_n$.

1)So for $Z_9$, subrings generated by $\vec 3$ = $\vec 6$ is both maximal and minimal ideal of $Z_9$.

2) For $Z_{10}$ , subrings generated by $\vec 2 =\vec 4 =\vec 6= \vec 8$ &  $\vec 5$ are maximal as well as minimal.

3) For $Z_{14}$, subrings generated by $\vec 2 = \vec 4 =\vec 6 =\vec 8 =\vec 10=\vec 12$ and $\vec 7$ are both maximal and minimal ideal.

Am I right here?

Comment: Where is $Z_8$?

Comment: For $Z_8$ , the subrings generated by $\vec 2$ is maximal and that by $\vec 4$ is minimal.

Comment: All correct.${}$